# Whats the meaning docker local volume?

Tags: docker

Have some confusion for "drive local" means ,

```
shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
```

This folder is not being created on the local machine (outside the docker),
So what it stands for ? why its needed?
where it actually exist?

see:

```
version: "3.6"
volumes:
  shared-workspace:
    name: "hadoop-distributed-file-system"
    driver: local
services:
  jupyterlab:
    image: jupyterlab:3.0.0-spark-3.0.0
    container_name: jupyterlab
    ports:
      - 8828:8888
      - 4040:4040
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "volumes" in Docker's terminology. It is used to persist data that your container is generating.

Volumes are normally created in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` (if you use Linux).

The difference between bind mount (`/opt/workspace:/opt/workspace`) and volumes (`shared-workspace:/opt/workspace`) is that bind mount depends on the OS: its file structure, folder's accessibility, user's rights etc, while volumes do not.

Bind mounts could be used in light (personal/testing) projects, while volumes are more for production usage.

Check out [Docker's documentation on data managing](https://docs.docker.com/storage/#more-details-about-mount-types) - they have good use cases for both bind mounts and volumes.

Answer (score 2):

Each volume driver supports ways to handle **where** and **how** to store information. It's sort of like file systems. For example there is a [ssh driver](https://github.com/vieux/docker-volume-sshfs) with which you can volume a directory contained in another machine into a docker container. The `local` driver is just a driver that stores the volume in your own machine storage but does not specify where. However you can find all the volumes in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` directory. You don't need to though. Docker handles all of the machinery for you.